# Elemento HTML debajo del otro

Tags: html

Necesito posicionar un botón debajo de un contenedor div, el problema es que el botón siempre me figura arriba o en el medio del formulario.

El siguiente es el texto HTML

```
<div >
  <div className="contenedor_central">
    <strong>Completá tus datos</strong>
    
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="floating">Nombre</IonLabel>
      <IonInput ></IonInput>
    </IonItem>
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="floating">Apellido</IonLabel>
      <IonInput ></IonInput>
    </IonItem>
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="floating">E-mail</IonLabel>
      <IonInput></IonInput>
    </IonItem>
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="floating">Clave</IonLabel>
      <IonInput ></IonInput>
    </IonItem>
  </div>
  <Boton name="Continuar" onClick={this.handleShow}></Boton>
</div>
```

El siguiente es la implementación CSS

```
.contenedor_central {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Como puedo modificar esto?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Son etiquetas definidas por el framework ionic, más allá de eso, son etiquetas normales como un <p>, etc.

Answer (score 0):

El button debe estar dentro del div con la clase contenedor_central

```
<div>
      <div class="contenedor_central">
        <strong>Completá tus datos</strong>
        
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Nombre</ion-label>
          <ion-input ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Apellido</ion-label>
          <ion-input ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">E-mail</ion-label>
          <ion-input></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Clave</ion-label>
          <ion-input ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        
        <button name="Continuar" onClick={this.handleShow}>Continuar</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```